# Transfer functions for systems with no input but with feedback

Tags: control-theory

This is a system of differential equations with a single loop feedback(piecewise-function):(I have also drawn a control system diagram below for this very system)
$$\frac{\mathrm{dx} }{\mathrm{d} t}=y$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{dy} }{\mathrm{d} t}=z $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{dz} }{\mathrm{d} t}=ax+by+cz+\beta x|x| $$
I'm wondering if one could define a transfer function in this case.(?)

The aim is to find regions of stability and instability. Notice that the system has become non-linear because of the piecewise-feedback function.
[image: Below is a control system diagram for the system with no input]

Is it possible to find the transfer function for this system? In a paper with a similar system having a single loop feedback system, the authors have computed the **'linear transfer function'**. How did they go about doing that and what is a linear transfer function?

[Link to paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X81902638) (see page 3)

Answer (score 1):

You have to split your closed loop in the linear part and the nonlinear part.

You have already done it in your below picture. For computing the linear transfer function (LTI), just delete the nonlinear block and simplify the rest of blocks choosing as input and output where the nonlinear block is attached to the linear part. In your picture, $x$ should be the output and the input should be the input to the first integrator.

After this, you will have two blocks, one linear (represented by your LTI), and the other nonlinear block.

You can use the well known results for LTI systems about one operation point, but not for every $x$.